# how to make a seek bar to get moved automatically in an android app

Tags: java, android, seekbar

in my app i want to place a seek bar. i want the seek bar to be move by its own as like in the media player a bar to show the remaining duration of the song.

When the user start to move from one location to the other, i am calculating the distance that the user traveling from one place to the other. So in order to show visualization i am trying to show the seek bar.

Is there any other layout for this....

Can anyone give me some example......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SeekBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) extends `ProgressBar`, so you can set its position as you would with a `ProgressBar`. BTW, if you only need to *visualize* the distance, use a `ProgressBar`.

With `ProgressBar.setMax()` you set the top value, with `ProgressBar.setProgress()` you set the current value.

Answer (score 0):

```
              public void seek updater()                              
            {               
      if(media.isPlaying())           
              {                  
             SeekBar s=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);                    
             s.setProgress(m.getCurrentPosition());                       
             Runnable r=new Runnable() 
                           {                                                           
                    @Override                                                       
                 public void run() {                                            
                  seekupdater();                                                    
                      }                                                         
                  };                                                       
             new Handler().postDelayed(r,1000);
           }
             }
```

just create a method like the above and call it when u press the play button.
i found this http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/simple-android-mp3-media-player very interesting,this may also help to find your answer.